# Conjugation and simple group

Tags: group-theory

I'd like to prove group $G$ is simple if and only if for every pair $g,h \in G$ ($g \ne 1$), $h$ can always be written product of finite number conjugates of $g$ and $g^{-1}$.

Comment: Have you shown implication in one of the directions? If $G$ has some non-trivial proper normal subgroup, can you find elements $g$ and $h$ not satisfying the given?

Comment: Your question would likely attract more positive attention if you said what you'd tried to do to work out the answer for yourself (or where you're stuck).

Answer (score 5):

Hint: look at the subgroup of $G$ generated by the conjugacy class of $g \in G$ and observe that this subgroup is normal.

Comment: Nice, simple and short accurate hint. +1